# Bitwise checking for signed multiplication overflow giving unexpected results

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, overflow

I am having difficulty writing a function that verifies whether the multiplication of two signed ints would exceed the bounds of an integer using bitwise operations.

One of the tests passes two ints: -40 and 7. The product is -280. This test should pass since -280 is well within the acceptable integer boundaries, but my function tells me it fails. I notice that every time I pass two ints that produce a negative product, I get the same incorrect result. Code and test are below. Thank you for any help!

I've tried printing out the binary strings along every step to figure out why the ending right-shift produces 1.
For this program the condition **must** take the form of: hiproduct = (loproduct >> 31).

```c
/* 
Function: Take two integers and determine if their product would produce an overflow within Integer boundaries using bit manipulation.
*/

bool tmult_ok(int x, int y) {
    long lx = (long)x;
    long ly = (long)y;
    long hiproduct = lx * ly; // These two are intentionally the same
    long loproduct = lx * ly; // and become different once masks apply
    printf("products: %d\n", hiproduct);

    long himask = 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
    long lomask = 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
    hiproduct = hiproduct & himask;
    loproduct = loproduct & lomask;

    printf("TMult result: %d, %d\n", hiproduct, loproduct);
    printf("Shifted loproduct: %d\n", (loproduct >> 31));
    return (hiproduct == (loproduct >> 31));
}

// Excerpt from main() in the test.c file -- not actual location!
int int1 = -40;
int int2 = 7;
assert(tmult_ok(int1, int2)); // True if no overflow would occur
printf("TMult Success Complete\n");
```

When run, I receive the following output:

```
products: -280
TMult result: 0, -280
Shifted loproduct: 1
Assertion failed: (tmult_ok(int3, int4)), function main, file test.c, line 24.
Abort trap: 6
```

The expected result is that the condition in the return statement is true, and thus would return true.

Comment: Do you assert that `sizeof(int)==4`?

Comment: You stated different conditions in the description and in the program: _hiproduct = (loproduct >> 31)_ vs. `hiproduct == (loproduct >> 31)`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of -280 is  0xfffffee8. If you right shift with 31, due to sign extension , the end result will be 0xffffffff(-1)

Comment: Hi Surendar, thanks for your reply. I just tested the code with that change and it is causing every test before it to fail. Furthermore in the directions for this program we are told we must keep the right-shift to 31 bits, so I don't think that is where the error lies. I think my assumption that loproduct >> 31 must equal 0 is wrong however so I will edit my question.

Comment: Yes you shouldn't right shift with 32.because it can cause round shift(zero shift).so, always you have to shift like following.. val >>(shiftval - 1) then val >>(1).In your case loproduct >> 31 first and againt do loproduct>>1. It will give right output, I hope